# my work permit expired, I have a Florida profit corporation (Inc), can I receive income via 1099-SEC? and declare taxes?

Tags: income-tax, form-1099, sole-proprietorship

I was working in the US as a resident and had a valid work permit.
I had to travel in December 2019, then the pandemic hit, I was stuck abroad and my work permit expired.
I have a Sole Proprietor Company through which I received income during 2020.
Now I have to declare taxes using the 1099-SEC form
Is this a crime??

Comment: Did you work after your work permit expired? If so, you have a problem. If not, then declaring taxes after the permit expired should be fine. You need the permit to work, not to pay taxes.

Comment: @user253751: It sounds like the OP's work authorization expired after they left the US. If so, the OP does not need work authorization in the US to work outside the US.

Comment: It also sounds a bit like the asker has a company in the US which made income (e.g. passively) but didn't do work in the US. But the asker needs to give more information.

Comment: There is no such form as 1099-SEC.

Comment: I'm confused.  In the title you mention that you have a corporation, but in the body of the question you mention a sole-proprietorship.  Which is it?

Comment: Not sure why you'd think reporting your income would be a crime. The other way around - not reporting it would be a crime.

However, if you're no longer a US resident, then maybe you don't need to pay US taxes on it at all. It sounds like you haven't been in the US at all in 2020, why do you think you need to report anything at all?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I suspect it's 1099-**N**EC

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not you are working illegally, you have to declare your personal income (on Form 1040) and any business income (on Form 1040, Schedule C).

This is why Al Capone should have declared his illegal income and paid his taxes.